# Singular or plural nouns after "if any"

Tags: grammar, determiners

Should I use singular or plural nouns with **if any**?

- **If any contestant does** not follow the rules, he/she will be expelled from the competition.
- **If any contestants do** not follow the rules, they will be expelled from the competition.

If they are both correct, Would you prefer a singular noun or a plural one after **if any**?

I know It's better to say:

- Any contestant not following the rules will be expelled from the competition.

For a non native speaker like me, It is a problem to decide whether I should use plural or singular nouns after **if any**.

Can anyone who is a teacher or has good knowledge of the language please explain this?

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure 'any' is an adjective in your two example sentences. See [M-W definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/any) #1.

Adjectives do not give number to the nouns they modify, and the use of 'if' is irrelevant. So the verb must simply agree in number with the noun, either 'contestant' or 'contestants'.

Both of those examples are correct.

Comment: It's more accurate to say that *few* adjectives in English mark number.  For example, "few".  Also, "many", "one", "this", "these", and "several" others.  In these cases, there must be numeric agreement between the adjectives and the nouns they directly modify.

Comment: I would have thought examples were determiners rather than adjectives. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also Gary, could you look at a question I asked you under "Why this sentence is grammatically incorrect"?

Comment: A difference in perspective and terminology.  One perspective considers *determiner* to be a word class separate from *adjective*.  Another considers it a semantic role that some adjectives sometimes fill.  In "this one example", "this" takes a determinative role and "one" takes a descriptive role.  In "one example", that same word "one" is determinative.  Did the word class change?

Comment: And I'm still pondering whether there's a relationship between telicity and the use of perfect aspect constructions.

Comment: Thanks, Gary. I've since noticed my determiner question was somewhat moot. If those special adjectives - or determiners, or whatever - must agree with the noun they modify, then the verb must agree with the noun is always valid. And I'll keep that other question open in my browser until your pondering is complete. Much appreciated. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To my own ear as a native speaker 'any contestants' is uncomfortable for whatever reason.

I would always say 'If any of the contestants ...' or 'if any among the contestants'.

One is singling out from among a plural.

I wait for comments or down-votes to tell me if I am wrong . . .